# Navigate Flutter App from Notification Action

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-navigation

I want to show a notification containing one or more actions and when those buttons are pressed, I want to navigate to a specific route in a Flutter app, even when the app is closed.
(I never really worked with native code.)
I create the notification via a messaging channel:

```
//Code shortened but leading code is irrelevant, as this code does show a notification
val launchIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)

val pLaunchIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

val buttonIntent = Intent(context, ButtonReceiver::class.java);

val pButtonIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "My_Id")
.setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
.setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
.setContentText(notificationText)
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
.setContentIntent(pLaunchIntent)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
.setColor(Color.CYAN)
.addAction(smallIcon, "Test", pButtonIntent)

val someNotificationId = 1;

notify(someNotificationId, builder.build())
```

This class extends a BroadcastReceiver and it should act on button tap

```
class ButtonReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val launchIntent = context!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    context.startActivity(launchIntent)
    FlutterNotificationPlugin.channel.invokeMethod("navigate", "/route")
    Log.i("Notifications", "Invoked method")
    }
}
```

My idea was that when the app is launched via the action click, I first start the flutter app and then invoke a method that tells the Flutter App to navigate to the corresponding route. The channel itself works, but when I click the action, nothing happends. The app is not launched.

I also added the following to the AndroidManifest.xml for the Flutter App

```xml
<receiver android:name="me.flutter_notification_plugin.ButtonReceiver"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle intent from notification in `MainActivity` (main activity for your app) in `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` methods and call method from Flutter side. For example:

Android:

1. declare a method for handle intent:

```kotlin
private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
    methodChannel?.invokeMethod(
        "notificationClick",
        mapOf(
            "notificationData" to intent.getData(),
        )
    )
}
```

2. Add method call to `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` and put to `handleIntent` intent from methods.

Flutter:

1. In `main` function call method that declares app behavior for notification handling:

```dart
void main() {
  // Code before app start
  initializeNotificationHandler();
  // Start app after this comment
}

void initializeNotificationHandler() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (isAndroid()) {
    const methodChannel = MethodChannel('com.yourcompanyname.notifications/handle');
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      if (call.method == 'notificationClick') {
        final data = call.arguments['notificationData'];
        jumpToPage(data['pageToOpen']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Notice: you can use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or other state management to change current screen in app (store current screen in a model, when you handled notification, change screen and refresh state).

UPDATE: this is an example of `MainActivity` class on Android side:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "com.exampleapp.channel"

    private var methodChannel: MethodChannel? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (intent?.action == ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICK) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                handleNotificationIntent(intent, false)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        methodChannel?.invokeMethod(
            "notificationClick",
            mapOf(
                "notificationData" to intent.getData(),
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (intent.action == EXTRA_SERVICE_ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICK) {
            handleNotificationIntent(intent, true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however, since the code lifes inside of a flutter plugin, the "entry point" does not extend a FlutterActivity, but rather a FlutterPlugin and the MethodCallHandler. Do you know how that works, too?

Comment: Can you explain what are you mean about "entry point"?

Comment: Normally, you'd have the Kotlin - or Javaclass called MainActivity. But in a Flutter Plugin, there is no such class. Instead, there is a class which extends FlutterPlugin and MethodCallHandler, and it overrides the methods onAttachedToEngine and onMethodCall, but there is no onCreate.

Comment: You have an activity that extends from `FlutterActivity` and it is an activity that you can use for handling intents from notifications.

Comment: Sorry to hit you up again this late, but I just couldn't get it to work.Would you mind posting a snippet of the main kotlin file, please?